# array conversion to the custom format

Tags: php, arrays

I have trying to solve this from past 5 hours result not came as i espected..  below the sample data which i have receive from a function.. please scroll down

```
Array
(
    [35] => Array
        (
            [36] => 
            [37] => Array
                (
                    [44] => 
                    [45] => 
                    [43] => 
                    [42] => 
                    [41] => 
                    [40] => 
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [3] => 
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [25] => 
                    [146] => 
                    [23] => 
                    [22] => 
                    [8] => 
                    [9] => 
                    [12] => Array
                        (
                            [20] => 
                            [19] => 
                        )

                )

        )
```

What i wanted is the ex: "key value 35" having a reclusive array and i want to list all keys of its array

Example:

```
    $output_required = array(
                35 => array(
                    36, 37, 44, 45, 43, 42, 41,40
                ),
                36 => array(

                ),
                37 => array(
                    44,45,43,42,41,40
                ),
                1 => array(
                    3,2,25,146,23,22,8,9,12,20,19
                )
//Continue 3,2,25 etc
            );
```

Full DATA If you are working on solving my problem. :)

```
 $data_array = unserialize('a:9:{i:35;a:2:{i:36;s:0:"";i:37;a:6:{i:44;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:43;s:0:"";i:42;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";}}i:1;a:2:{i:3;s:0:"";i:2;a:7:{i:25;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:23;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:12;a:2:{i:20;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";}}}i:33;a:2:{i:34;s:0:"";i:51;a:2:{i:135;s:0:"";i:52;s:0:"";}}i:117;a:2:{i:118;a:4:{i:130;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:127;s:0:"";}i:119;a:9:{i:126;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";i:125;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:120;s:0:"";}}i:59;a:3:{i:64;a:2:{i:134;s:0:"";i:133;s:0:"";}i:60;a:2:{i:63;s:0:"";i:62;s:0:"";}i:61;a:5:{i:145;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:141;s:0:"";}}i:97;a:4:{i:101;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";}i:82;a:4:{i:86;s:0:"";i:83;a:2:{i:85;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";}i:87;a:2:{i:89;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";}i:136;a:4:{i:140;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";}}i:92;a:4:{i:96;s:0:"";i:95;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";}i:47;a:6:{i:57;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:54;s:0:"";i:53;s:0:"";i:49;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";}}');
```

This is the code what i have tried

```
public  function clean_cat_path($datas, $parent_ids = array())
    {
        static $array,$parent_ids;

        foreach ($datas as $k => $data) {
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $parent_ids[] = $k;
                $this->clean_cat_path($data, $parent_ids);
            }
            if (empty($parent_ids)) {
                $array[$k][$k] = $k;
            } else {
                foreach ($parent_ids as $id) {
                    $array[$k][$id] = $id;
                }
            }
            $parent_ids = array();
        }
        return $array;
    }
```

ITS SOLVED MYSELF sorry if you didn't understand correctly

```
<?php

class test_class
{
    static $cat_list;

    public function execute()
    {
        $data_array = unserialize('a:9:{i:35;a:2:{i:36;s:0:"";i:37;a:6:{i:44;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:43;s:0:"";i:42;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";}}i:1;a:2:{i:3;s:0:"";i:2;a:7:{i:25;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:23;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:12;a:2:{i:20;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";}}}i:33;a:2:{i:34;s:0:"";i:51;a:2:{i:135;s:0:"";i:52;s:0:"";}}i:117;a:2:{i:118;a:4:{i:130;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:127;s:0:"";}i:119;a:9:{i:126;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";i:125;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:120;s:0:"";}}i:59;a:3:{i:64;a:2:{i:134;s:0:"";i:133;s:0:"";}i:60;a:2:{i:63;s:0:"";i:62;s:0:"";}i:61;a:5:{i:145;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:141;s:0:"";}}i:97;a:4:{i:101;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";}i:82;a:4:{i:86;s:0:"";i:83;a:2:{i:85;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";}i:87;a:2:{i:89;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";}i:136;a:4:{i:140;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";}}i:92;a:4:{i:96;s:0:"";i:95;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";}i:47;a:6:{i:57;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:54;s:0:"";i:53;s:0:"";i:49;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";}}');
        return $this->clean_cat_path($data_array);
    }

    public function clean_cat_path($datas)
    {
        foreach ($datas as $k => $data) {
            $this->cat_list[$k][$k] = $k;
            if (!empty($data)) {
                $this->list_keys_of($data, $k);
                $this->clean_cat_path($data);
            }
        }
        return $this->cat_list;
    }

    private function list_keys_of($data, $key_id)
    {
        foreach ($data as $k => $d) {
            $this->cat_list[$key_id][] = $k;
            if (!empty($d)) {
                $this->list_keys_of($d, $key_id);
            }
        }
    }

}

$test = new test_class();
$output = $test->execute();

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: In the wanted output, the keys 36, 37 and 44, 45, etc are on the same level. Are you sure that's what you want ?

Comment: could you explain more clearly how the output relates to the input? You are obviously somehow trying to "flatten" the input, but I can't figure out why certain values belong with a particular key. Could you make a very simple example to explain this?

Comment: @Theox content edited please refresh  ...

Comment: Sorry, but your example doesn't make sense. It looks like you're trying to flatten the output but in your example, a key is both top level and sub-level somewhere else. That just makes me scratch my head. Even with the updated example code, it's still not clear what you want. I think you'll have to broaden your explanation a bit.

Comment: Why would you have 36 and 37 show up twice? Why not 3?

Comment: @Anthony Yes 3 is also required.. i just shown how the output should come.

Comment: Does the "ITS SOLVED MYSELF" mean that you have your solution? Because it doesn't seem to give the values you asked for - the first entry in your result array is `(35,36,37,...)` - for each key, "the key itself" shows up as the first item in your result. Do you still want further help?

Comment: @user3257284 - The solution you provided doesn't generate the example you provided. if you want actual help, it would be great if you could give both an example of what you are actually wanting and some explanation of the relationship between the input and the output. Also, your example code probably doesn't work. I just ran it and it has array members such as : `[97] => 97,[98] => 101`.  If that is right, you have not provided nearly enough background on what you are trying to output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first idea :

```
$array = unserialize('a:9:{i:35;a:2:{i:36;s:0:"";i:37;a:6:{i:44;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:43;s:0:"";i:42;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";}}i:1;a:2:{i:3;s:0:"";i:2;a:7:{i:25;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:23;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:12;a:2:{i:20;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";}}}i:33;a:2:{i:34;s:0:"";i:51;a:2:{i:135;s:0:"";i:52;s:0:"";}}i:117;a:2:{i:118;a:4:{i:130;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:127;s:0:"";}i:119;a:9:{i:126;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";i:125;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:120;s:0:"";}}i:59;a:3:{i:64;a:2:{i:134;s:0:"";i:133;s:0:"";}i:60;a:2:{i:63;s:0:"";i:62;s:0:"";}i:61;a:5:{i:145;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:141;s:0:"";}}i:97;a:4:{i:101;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";}i:82;a:4:{i:86;s:0:"";i:83;a:2:{i:85;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";}i:87;a:2:{i:89;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";}i:136;a:4:{i:140;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";}}i:92;a:4:{i:96;s:0:"";i:95;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";}i:47;a:6:{i:57;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:54;s:0:"";i:53;s:0:"";i:49;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";}}');
$output = array();

function get_every_key($arr)
{    
    global $output; 
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value )
    {
        if (is_array($value)) 
        {
            $output[$key]=array_keys($value);
            get_every_key($value);
        }
    }

}

get_every_key($array);
print_r($output);
```

This will find every sub array in your initial array, and extract the keys of this sub-array. The issue is that it only gets the first-level keys of the sub-array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this.

It's pretty short and it does what you want.

```
$arr_initial_data = unserialize('a:9:{i:35;a:2:{i:36;s:0:"";i:37;a:6:{i:44;s:0:"";i:45;s:0:"";i:43;s:0:"";i:42;s:0:"";i:41;s:0:"";i:40;s:0:"";}}i:1;a:2:{i:3;s:0:"";i:2;a:7:{i:25;s:0:"";i:146;s:0:"";i:23;s:0:"";i:22;s:0:"";i:8;s:0:"";i:9;s:0:"";i:12;a:2:{i:20;s:0:"";i:19;s:0:"";}}}i:33;a:2:{i:34;s:0:"";i:51;a:2:{i:135;s:0:"";i:52;s:0:"";}}i:117;a:2:{i:118;a:4:{i:130;s:0:"";i:129;s:0:"";i:128;s:0:"";i:127;s:0:"";}i:119;a:9:{i:126;s:0:"";i:131;s:0:"";i:132;s:0:"";i:125;s:0:"";i:124;s:0:"";i:121;s:0:"";i:122;s:0:"";i:123;s:0:"";i:120;s:0:"";}}i:59;a:3:{i:64;a:2:{i:134;s:0:"";i:133;s:0:"";}i:60;a:2:{i:63;s:0:"";i:62;s:0:"";}i:61;a:5:{i:145;s:0:"";i:144;s:0:"";i:143;s:0:"";i:142;s:0:"";i:141;s:0:"";}}i:97;a:4:{i:101;s:0:"";i:100;s:0:"";i:99;s:0:"";i:98;s:0:"";}i:82;a:4:{i:86;s:0:"";i:83;a:2:{i:85;s:0:"";i:84;s:0:"";}i:87;a:2:{i:89;s:0:"";i:88;s:0:"";}i:136;a:4:{i:140;s:0:"";i:139;s:0:"";i:138;s:0:"";i:137;s:0:"";}}i:92;a:4:{i:96;s:0:"";i:95;s:0:"";i:94;s:0:"";i:93;s:0:"";}i:47;a:6:{i:57;s:0:"";i:58;s:0:"";i:54;s:0:"";i:53;s:0:"";i:49;s:0:"";i:48;s:0:"";}}');

function clean_cat_path($arr_data, $int_parent_id) {
   global $arr_final_data;
   if (count($arr_data) > 0 && is_array($arr_data)) {
      foreach ($arr_data as $k=>$v) {
         if ($int_parent_id) {
            $arr_final_data[$int_parent_id][$k] = $k;
         }
         if (is_array($v)) {
            if ($int_parent_id) {
               clean_cat_path($v, $int_parent_id);
            } else {
               clean_cat_path($v, $k);
            }
         }   
      }      
   }         
}            
clean_cat_path($arr_initial_data, NULL);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr_final_data);
echo "</pre>";
```

It the final array should be as this at the end:

```
array(9) {
  [35]=>
  array(8) {
    [36]=>
    int(36)
    [37]=>
    int(37)
    [44]=>
    int(44)
    [45]=>
    int(45)
    [43]=>
    int(43)
    [42]=>
    int(42)
    [41]=>
    int(41)
    [40]=>
    int(40)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(11) {
    [3]=>
    int(3)
    [2]=>
    int(2)
    [25]=>
    int(25)
    [146]=>
    int(146)
    [23]=>
    int(23)
    [22]=>
    int(22)
    [8]=>
    int(8)
    [9]=>
    int(9)
    [12]=>
    int(12)
    [20]=>
    int(20)
    [19]=>
    int(19)
  }
  [33]=>
  array(4) {
    [34]=>
    int(34)
    [51]=>
    int(51)
    [135]=>
    int(135)
    [52]=>
    int(52)
  }
  [117]=>
  array(15) {
    [118]=>
    int(118)
    [130]=>
    int(130)
    [129]=>
    int(129)
    [128]=>
    int(128)
    [127]=>
    int(127)
    [119]=>
    int(119)
    [126]=>
    int(126)
    [131]=>
    int(131)
    [132]=>
    int(132)
    [125]=>
    int(125)
    [124]=>
    int(124)
    [121]=>
    int(121)
    [122]=>
    int(122)
    [123]=>
    int(123)
    [120]=>
    int(120)
  }
  [59]=>
  array(12) {
    [64]=>
    int(64)
    [134]=>
    int(134)
    [133]=>
    int(133)
    [60]=>
    int(60)
    [63]=>
    int(63)
    [62]=>
    int(62)
    [61]=>
    int(61)
    [145]=>
    int(145)
    [144]=>
    int(144)
    [143]=>
    int(143)
    [142]=>
    int(142)
    [141]=>
    int(141)
  }
  [97]=>
  array(4) {
    [101]=>
    int(101)
    [100]=>
    int(100)
    [99]=>
    int(99)
    [98]=>
    int(98)
  }
  [82]=>
  array(12) {
    [86]=>
    int(86)
    [83]=>
    int(83)
    [85]=>
    int(85)
    [84]=>
    int(84)
    [87]=>
    int(87)
    [89]=>
    int(89)
    [88]=>
    int(88)
    [136]=>
    int(136)
    [140]=>
    int(140)
    [139]=>
    int(139)
    [138]=>
    int(138)
    [137]=>
    int(137)
  }
  [92]=>
  array(4) {
    [96]=>
    int(96)
    [95]=>
    int(95)
    [94]=>
    int(94)
    [93]=>
    int(93)
  }
  [47]=>
  array(6) {
    [57]=>
    int(57)
    [58]=>
    int(58)
    [54]=>
    int(54)
    [53]=>
    int(53)
    [49]=>
    int(49)
    [48]=>
    int(48)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you solved your problem but found this usefull please vote up. thank you